# SQL - Group and count duplicates row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea how to group and count duplicates row on mysql

below is the result that I got from my query

```
       ssn              +       checktime           +   nama            
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     
'196702031989031001'    +   '2018-08-03 07:33:02'   +   'FAJAR PERMADI'
'196810021993031001'    +   '2018-08-01 07:33:25'   +   'ANDRI ANGGORO, SH'
'196911052000031001'    +   '2018-08-03 07:47:22'   +   'SEMI TEDDY RORY, SS'
'196912221994032001'    +   '2018-08-01 08:03:59'   +   'AI SALATUN'
'196912221994032001'    +   '2018-08-02 09:34:11'   +   'AI SALATUN'
'196912221994032001'    +   '2018-08-03 07:33:18'   +   'AI SALATUN'
'197012051993031001'    +   '2018-08-01 07:58:47'   +   'AHMAD SODIKIN, SH'
'197012192001121001'    +   '2018-08-01 09:54:21'   +   'JUARA PAHALA MARBUN, ST'
'197012192001121001'    +   '2018-08-02 09:39:41'   +   'JUARA PAHALA MARBUN, ST'
```

and below is my query

```
SELECT a.ssn, a.checktime, b.nama
FROM hki_kepegawaian.fo_absensi a
left join hki_kepegawaian.fo_pegawai b on a.ssn = b.nip  
where (substring(cast(checktime as DATE), 6, 2) = '08') 
and (cast(a.checktime as TIME)) >= '07:30:00' and (cast(a.checktime as 
TIME)) <= '10:00:00'
and (substring(golongan, 1, 2)) NOT IN ('IV')
group by ssn, cast(a.checktime as date)
```

and below is result that I expected

```
        ssn             +       checktime           +   nama                        +   total
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                                                                                                   
'196702031989031001'    +   '2018-08-03 07:33:02'   +   'FAJAR PERMADI'             +   1
'196810021993031001'    +   '2018-08-01 07:33:25'   +   'ANDRI ANGGORO, SH'         +   1
'196911052000031001'    +   '2018-08-03 07:47:22'   +   'SEMI TEDDY RORY, SS'       +   1
'196912221994032001'    +   '2018-08-01 08:03:59'   +   'AI SALATUN'                +   3
'197012051993031001'    +   '2018-08-01 07:58:47'   +   'AHMAD SODIKIN, SH'         +   1
'197012192001121001'    +   '2018-08-01 09:54:21'   +   'JUARA PAHALA MARBUN, ST'   +   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output implies that you want to report the record having the earliest check time for each ssn/nama group of records.  For the count, it just looks like the total number of records in each group.

```
SELECT
    a.ssn,
    MIN(CAST(a.checktime AS date)) AS checktime,
    b.nama,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM hki_kepegawaian.fo_absensi a
LEFT JOIN hki_kepegawaian.fo_pegawai b
    ON a.ssn = b.nip  
WHERE
    MONTH(checktime) = 8 AND
    CAST(a.checktime AS TIME) BETWEEN '07:30:00' AND '10:00:00' AND
    SUBSTRING(golongan, 1, 2)) <> 'IV'
GROUP BY
    a.ssn, CAST(a.checktime AS date);
```

Comment: hi tim, you're right. I want to get the earliest checktime for each ssn. but if i use `count(*)` it will give me the total checktime in month of each ssn, not the earliest checktime only of ssn

Comment: @rafitio Using `COUNT(*)` would generate your expected `total` column.  If you want something else, then update your data to show this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim that you seem to want to take the earliest time.  This is accomplished with a `group by` in this case.

However, there are some other fixes to the query that I would suggest:

- Do not use string operations on date/times.
- Use meaningful table aliases that are abbreviations for the table.
- Include all unaggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.
- Use `LIKE` where appropriate.

So, I would suggest:

```
SELECT a.ssn, a.checktime, p.nama
FROM hki_kepegawaian.fo_absensi a LEFT JOIN
     hki_kepegawaian.fo_pegawai b 
     ON a.ssn = p.nip  
WHERE MONTH(checktime) = 8 AND
      CAST(a.checktime as TIME) >= '07:30:00' AND
      CAST(a.checktime as TIME)) <= '10:00:00' AND
      golongan NOT LIKE 'IV%'
GROUP BY a.ssn, p.nama;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [count() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html).

I can't check  whether it works, but try the following query:

```
SELECT a.ssn, a.checktime, b.nama, count(*) as total
FROM hki_kepegawaian.fo_absensi a
left join hki_kepegawaian.fo_pegawai b on a.ssn = b.nip  
where (substring(cast(checktime as DATE), 6, 2) = '08') 
and (cast(a.checktime as TIME)) >= '07:30:00' and (cast(a.checktime as 
TIME)) <= '10:00:00'
and (substring(golongan, 1, 2)) NOT IN ('IV')
group by ssn, nama
Having total>=1
```